# Fixed navbar / header between React Native views

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm attempting to create a consistent navbar / header in my React Native app.

In my code's current state, the entire view is getting swapped. Works fine, but the navbar / header scroll with the view (as you would assume) which looks kind of silly.

Is there a way to limit the Navigator view change to a certain block of my code, or am I attempting to do this entirely the wrong way?

I've tried a few silly things like wrapping the parent component's Navigator element in a view, etc.

in my main parent component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Navigator
      initialRoute = {{
        id: 'HomePage'
      }}
      renderScene={
        this.navigatorRenderScene
      }
      configureScene={(route, routeStack) => {
        if (route.sceneConfig) {
          return route.sceneConfig;
        }
        return Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump;
      }
      }
    />
  )
}

navigatorRenderScene = (route, navigator) => {
  navigator = navigator
  switch (route.id){
    case 'HomePage':
      return( <HomePage navigator={navigator} title='HomePage' /> )
    case 'Locations':
      return( <Locations navigator={navigator} title='Locations' /> )
  }
}
```

and to navigate between pages I'm just using this method from the child component.

```
onButtonPress() {
  console.log('going to locations')
  this.props.navigator.push({
    id: 'Locations',
    sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really stupid solution - Everything was working as it should, except the View wasn't rendering properly due to some kind of style issue. Giving it 'flex: 1' fixed it.